# Implementation of processing items asynchronously

Tags: c#

Is there any good implementation of processing queue items asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty old but this is the good one that I know off http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/inprocessasynservicesincs.aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you're using .NET 4, a lot of this comes for free out of the box.

If you've already got all the items, you can use [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=net-5.0). If you need a producer/consumer queue, you can use [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0) to wrap one of the concurrent collections (such as [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0) or [`ConcurrentStack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1?view=net-5.0)). How you use that is up to you; there's a [blog post here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem) going into a detailed example, and there are probably other similar posts around too. (You might want to look at the [Parallel Team Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/) for a lot more material.)

Comment: +1 For getting into 4.0 :) , i was just writing about this also.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` blocks the calling thread until it completes all of them so that's not really going to help 'process queue items asynchronously' now is it? or did question really mean "in parallel" rather than "asynchronously"?

Comment: That's great but unfortunately, i am using .Net 3.5

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at a Producer/Consumer pattern if you are unfortunate enough not to be using .net 4.

Here is my code I have disassembled, my apologies for the mess but you should be able to use this by adding to a project and recompiling, then creating your process using the resulting dll.

Enum for ChannelState:

```
public enum ChannelState
{
    WaitingForSend,
    WaitingForReceive,
    Open
}
```

Interfaces:

```
public interface IChannel<TMessage>
{
    // Methods
    TMessage Receive();
    void Send(TMessage message);

    // Properties
    bool CanReceive { get; }
    bool CanSend { get; }
    ChannelState State { get; }
}

using System;
public interface IReceiver<TMessage>
{
    // Events
    event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs<TMessage>> MessageReceived;

    // Methods
    void Activate();
    void Deactivate();

    // Properties
    bool IsActive { get; }
}
```

Concrete classes:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System;
public class BufferedChannel<TMessage> : IChannel<TMessage>
{
    // Fields
    private int _blockedReceivers;
    private int _blockedSenders;
    private Queue<TMessage> _buffer;
    private int _capacity;
    private EventWaitHandle _capacityAvailableEvent;
    private EventWaitHandle _messagesAvailableEvent;

    // Methods
    public BufferedChannel()
    {
        this._buffer = new Queue<TMessage>();
        this._messagesAvailableEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        this._capacityAvailableEvent = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        this._capacity = 50;
    }

    public BufferedChannel(int bufferSize)
    {
        this._buffer = new Queue<TMessage>();
        this._messagesAvailableEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        this._capacityAvailableEvent = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        this._capacity = 50;
        if (bufferSize <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bufferSize", bufferSize, ExceptionMessages.ChannelsBufferSizeMustBeGreaterThanZero);
        }
        this._capacity = bufferSize;
    }

    public TMessage Receive()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref this._blockedReceivers);
        try
        {
            this._messagesAvailableEvent.WaitOne();
        }
        catch
        {
            lock (this._buffer)
            {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref this._blockedReceivers);
            }
            throw;
        }
        lock (this._buffer)
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref this._blockedReceivers);
            this._capacityAvailableEvent.Set();
            if ((this._buffer.Count - 1) > this._blockedReceivers)
            {
                this._messagesAvailableEvent.Set();
            }
            return this._buffer.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    public void Send(TMessage message)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref this._blockedSenders);
        try
        {
            this._capacityAvailableEvent.WaitOne();
        }
        catch
        {
            lock (this._buffer)
            {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref this._blockedSenders);
            }
            throw;
        }
        lock (this._buffer)
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref this._blockedSenders);
            this._buffer.Enqueue(message);
            if (this._buffer.Count < this.BufferSize)
            {
                this._capacityAvailableEvent.Set();
            }
            this._messagesAvailableEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    // Properties
    public int BufferCount
    {
        get
        {
            lock (this._buffer)
            {
                return this._buffer.Count;
            }
        }
    }

    public int BufferSize
    {
        get
        {
            lock (this._buffer)
            {
                return this._capacity;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (this._buffer)
            {
                if (value <= 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("BufferSize", value, ExceptionMessages.ChannelsBufferSizeMustBeGreaterThanZero);
                }
                this._capacity = value;
                if ((this._blockedSenders > 0) && (this._capacity > this._buffer.Count))
                {
                    this._capacityAvailableEvent.Set();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool CanReceive
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool CanSend
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ChannelState State
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._blockedSenders > 0)
            {
                return ChannelState.WaitingForReceive;
            }
            if (this._blockedReceivers > 0)
            {
                return ChannelState.WaitingForSend;
            }
            return ChannelState.Open;
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public sealed class Receiver<TMessage> : Component, IReceiver<TMessage>
{
    // Fields
    private volatile bool _continue;
    private object _controlLock;
    private volatile bool _disposed;
    private Thread _receiverThread;
    private bool _receiving;
    private object _receivingLock;
    private object _threadLock;
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private IChannel<TMessage> channel;

    // Events
    public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs<TMessage>> MessageReceived;

    // Methods
    public Receiver(IChannel<TMessage> channel)
    {
        this._controlLock = new object();
        this._threadLock = new object();
        this._receivingLock = new object();
        if (channel == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("channel");
        }
        this.Channel = channel;
    }

    public void Activate()
    {
        this.CheckDisposed();
        lock (this._controlLock)
        {
            if (this._receiverThread != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            this._continue = true;
            this._receiverThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.RunAsync));
            this._receiverThread.IsBackground = true;
            this._receiverThread.Start();
        }
    }

    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (this._disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(base.GetType().Name);
        }
    }

    public void Deactivate()
    {
        lock (this._controlLock)
        {
            if (this._continue)
            {
                this._continue = false;
                lock (this._threadLock)
                {
                    if (this._receiverThread != null)
                    {
                        this.SafeInterrupt();
                        this._receiverThread.Join();
                        this._receiverThread = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.Deactivate();
            this._disposed = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnMessageReceived(TMessage message)
    {
        EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs<TMessage>> messageReceived = this.MessageReceived;
        if (messageReceived != null)
        {
            messageReceived(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs<TMessage>(message));
        }
    }

    private void RunAsync()
    {
        while (this._continue)
        {
            TMessage message = default(TMessage);
            bool flag = false;
            try
            {
                lock (this._receivingLock)
                {
                    this._receiving = true;
                }
                message = this.Channel.Receive();
                flag = true;
                lock (this._receivingLock)
                {
                    this._receiving = false;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
            {
            }
            if (!this._continue)
            {
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.Channel.Send(message);
                    return;
                }
                break;
            }
            this.OnMessageReceived(message);
        }
    }

    private void SafeInterrupt()
    {
        lock (this._receivingLock)
        {
            lock (this._threadLock)
            {
                if (this._receiving && (this._receiverThread != null))
                {
                    this._receiverThread.Interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Properties
    protected override bool CanRaiseEvents
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public IChannel<TMessage> Channel
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return this.channel;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        private set
        {
            this.channel = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            lock (this._controlLock)
            {
                return (this._receiverThread != null);
            }
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
public class MessageReceivedEventArgs<TMessage> : EventArgs
{
    // Fields
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private TMessage message;

    // Methods
    public MessageReceivedEventArgs(TMessage message)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }

    // Properties
    public TMessage Message
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return this.message;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        private set
        {
            this.message = value;
        }
    }
}

using System.Threading;
public class BlockingChannel<TMessage> : IChannel<TMessage>
{
    // Fields
    private TMessage _message;
    private EventWaitHandle _messageReceiveEvent;
    private EventWaitHandle _messageReceiveyEvent;
    private object _sendLock;
    private ChannelState _state;
    private object _stateLock;

    // Methods
    public BlockingChannel()
    {
        this._state = ChannelState.Open;
        this._stateLock = new object();
        this._messageReceiveyEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        this._messageReceiveEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        this._sendLock = new object();
    }

    public TMessage Receive()
    {
        this.State = ChannelState.WaitingForSend;
        this._messageReceiveyEvent.WaitOne();
        this._messageReceiveEvent.Set();
        this.State = ChannelState.Open;
        return this._message;
    }

    public void Send(TMessage message)
    {
        lock (this._sendLock)
        {
            this._message = message;
            this.State = ChannelState.WaitingForReceive;
            this._messageReceiveyEvent.Set();
            this._messageReceiveEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    // Properties
    public bool CanReceive
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool CanSend
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ChannelState State
    {
        get
        {
            lock (this._stateLock)
            {
                return this._state;
            }
        }
        private set
        {
            lock (this._stateLock)
            {
                this._state = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .NET 4 tasks.

```
var t = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessItem());
```

Use the ConcurrencyOptions to set the maximum degree of parallelism on that processing.

If you want to roll it yourself, use `BlockingCollection<T>` which provides blocking and bounding capabilities for thread-safe collections and implement a separate thread (or threads) for the consumer.